Error 70 permission denied when adding or deleting a file
I have a client. The code worked perfectly for years. But suddenly this error pops up on his and all of his coworkers' computers. Yet, when I run the same code on my own computer, I encounter no problems.
What we do is to create a simple log file so that coworkers cannot open a file if it is already opened by another user.
So auto_open creates the log file
auto_close deletes the lof file
Some lines in the auto_open procedure has been deleted since it is irrelevant to the question asked here
My knowledge of scripting runtime and objects is very limited. I typically rely on example code for that. Any assistance will be much appreciated.
Option Explicit
Private opndFile As String, oflePath As String


Sub auto_open()
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
    Dim flePath As String
    Dim packPath As String
    Dim bkNme As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nDatR As Long, nCntr As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each s In Sheets
        If s.Name = "Main Menu" Or s.Name = "Commodity" Or s.Name = "Sys" Or s.Name = "CommodCatg" Or s.Name = "Fabric Composition" Or s.Name = "Date" Then
            With s
                 .Visible = True
                 .Activate
                 Debug.Print s.Name
                .Unprotect Password:="bcts2601"
             End With
        End If
    Next s
    
    chkIfFldrsExist
    
    If (Right(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 20) = "\EUROTEX\Commodities") Then
        oflePath = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "Commodities", "OpenedFiles")
        opndFile = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "f")

    ElseIf (Right(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 8) = "\EUROTEX") Then
        oflePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OpenedFiles"
        opndFile = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "f")
    Else
        oflePath = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "Templates", "OpenedFiles")
        opndFile = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "f")
    End If
    
    If opndFile <> "Commodities.f" Then
        If (fs.FileExists(oflePath & "\" & opndFile)) Then 'oFlg.f")
            'Replace("alphabet", "bet", "hydro")
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "This file is open by another user ..." 'cal also get name out of text file if u want to display it here
            'close without deleting the flag file
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            createOpenFlag
        End If
    End If
    
    Set fs = Nothing
    


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     
     For Each s In Sheets
       If s.Name = "Main Menu" Or s.Name = "Commodity" Or s.Name = "Sys" Or s.Name = "CommodCatg" Or s.Name = "Fabric Composition" Or s.Name = "Date" Then

           With s
                .Activate
               .Unprotect Password:="bcts2601"
                If s.Name = "Commodity" Then
                    'CLEAR SELECTED FILTERS
                    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                    'ALLOW USER TO USE FILTERS
                    .EnableAutoFilter = True
                    'Re-index column D to eliminate Ref! problem with copy and paste errors
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    n = .Range("E10").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 9
                    .Range("D10") = 0
                    .Range("D11:D" & n).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=IF(CONCATENATE(RC[1],RC[2],RC[3],RC[4],RC[5],RC[6],RC[7],RC[8],RC[9],RC[10],RC[11],RC[12],RC[13],RC[14],RC[15],RC[16],RC[17],RC[18],RC[19],RC[20],RC[21],RC[22],RC[23],RC[24],RC[25],RC[26],RC[27],RC[28],RC[29],RC[30],RC[31],RC[32])="""","""",R[-1]C+1)"
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                    
                End If
                If s.Name = "Commodity" Then
                    .Protect Password:="bcts2601", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
                Else
                    .Protect Password:="bcts2601", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
                End If
                .EnableOutlining = True
                .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
               
            End With
        End If
    Next s
    
    sCommodity.Unprotect Password:="bcts2601"

    sCommodity.Activate
    'n = sCommodity.Range("E10").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("D:D"))
    sCommodity.Range("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Count
    If n > 1 Then
        nDatR = n + 9
        nCntr = 11
        Do Until nCntr > nDatR
            If sCommodity.Range("AC" & nCntr).Value = "" Then
                sCommodity.Range("AC" & nCntr).Value = DateSerial(Year:=2050, Month:=12, Day:=31)
            End If
            nCntr = nCntr + 1
        Loop
    End If
    If n > 2 Then
        sCommodity.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        sCommodity.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
            sCommodity.Range("AC10:AC1009"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
        With sCommodity.AutoFilter.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End If

    For Each s In Sheets
       With s
            .Activate
            If ActiveSheet.Name = "Commodity" Then
                With ActiveWindow
                    If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
                    .SplitColumn = 6
                    .SplitRow = 10
                    .FreezePanes = True
                End With
            Else
                With ActiveWindow
                    If .FreezePanes Then
                        .FreezePanes = False
                        .SplitColumn = 0
                        .SplitRow = 0
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next s



    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    
    For Each s In Sheets
        With s
            .Activate
            .Range("A1").Select
            ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        End With
    Next s

    packPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    sSys.Range("B1").Value = packPath
    bkNme = GetBook
    
    If bkNme = "Commodities.xlsm" Then
        sSys.Visible = xlHidden
        sDate.Visible = xlHidden
        sFabricComposition.Visible = xlHidden
        sCommodCatg.Visible = xlHidden
        sCommodity.Visible = xlHidden
        sMM.Visible = True
        sMM.Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        sMM.Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("prntRngeRectngle").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("xprtRngeRectngle").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("createwkBk").Visible = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    Else
        sMM.Visible = True
        sCommodity.Visible = True
        sFabricComposition.Visible = True
        sSys.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        sDate.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        sCommodCatg.Visible = xlVeryHidden
        sMM.Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        sMM.Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("prntRngeRectngle").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("xprtRngeRectngle").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("createwkBk").Visible = False

        ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetBook() As String
    GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Function

Function createOpenFlag()
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
    Dim txtf As Object
    'OpenedFiles
    Set txtf = fs.CreateTextFile(oflePath & "\" & opndFile, True)
    txtf.WriteLine Environ$("Username")
    Set fs = Nothing

End Function

Sub auto_close()
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill oflePath & "\" & opndFile           'ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\oFlg.f"
End Sub

Sub createTmpFoldr()
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim rF As New FileSystemObject
    Dim DocumentsPath As String


    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    FolderPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Temp\"
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    End If

    If Not rF.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then MkDir FolderPath


End Sub


Sub submitComposition()
    Dim curr As Worksheet
    Dim currAddr As String
    
    If Not (sFabricComposition.Range("F16").Value = 100) Then
        MsgBox "The Total %Composition of materials must add up to 100%. Please correct this.", vbExclamation, "Total %Composition"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set curr = Worksheets(sSys.Range("DA5").Value)
    currAddr = sSys.Range("DA2").Value
    curr.Activate
    curr.Range(currAddr).Activate
    curr.Range(currAddr).Value = sFabricComposition.Range("E20").Value
End Sub

Sub navSht()
    Dim curr As Worksheet
    
    Set curr = Worksheets(sSys.Range("H2").Value)
    curr.Activate

End Sub




Sub navHome()
    sMM.Activate
End Sub



Sub setComposition()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim actCol As Long, actRow As Long, actAddr As String

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    actAddr = ActiveCell.Address
    actCol = sht.Range(actAddr).Column
    actRow = sht.Range(actAddr).Row
    
    If (actCol <> sSys.Range("DA8").Value) Or (actRow < sSys.Range("DA11").Value) Or (actRow > sSys.Range("DA14").Value) Then
        MsgBox "Insertion of Total %Composition of materials is not allowed here.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Entry"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    sSys.Range("DA2").Value = actAddr
    sSys.Range("DA5").Value = sht.Name
    sFabricComposition.Activate
    
    
End Sub

Sub chkIfFldrsExist()
    Dim rF As New FileSystemObject
    Dim DocumentsPath As String

    'find out where user's Documents folder is
    sSys.Range("B1").Value = cmdTmplte.Path
    DocumentsPath = sSys.Range("B24").Value
    If Not rF.FolderExists(DocumentsPath) Then MkDir DocumentsPath
    DocumentsPath = sSys.Range("B25").Value
    If Not rF.FolderExists(DocumentsPath) Then MkDir DocumentsPath
    DocumentsPath = sSys.Range("B26").Value
    If Not rF.FolderExists(DocumentsPath) Then MkDir DocumentsPath
    DocumentsPath = sSys.Range("B27").Value
    If Not rF.FolderExists(DocumentsPath) Then MkDir DocumentsPath
    DocumentsPath = sSys.Range("B28").Value
    If Not rF.FolderExists(DocumentsPath) Then MkDir DocumentsPath
    DocumentsPath = sSys.Range("B29").Value
    If Not rF.FolderExists(DocumentsPath) Then MkDir DocumentsPath

End Sub


Has anything change on the network?

I cannot say. I do know that these files are stored in Dropbox.

Was the system updated ? But why not show the error? Those lines you deleted - how do you know they are not the cause ? or contribute to the cause?

Actually I have updated the code - so ALL code is now there. I have just deleted subroutines to make it easier for you to focus on the auto_open and auto_close routines. But like I said, trying to post the code gave challenges, so then I just posted all of it

Also, I logged in remotely to the clients computer because on my side I get no error, yet we share the same dropbox folder where the software run and store files. So I didn't capture the error - which occurs at in the Kill command line in auto_close routine - that is when I comment out the On Error Resume Next line
Sorry yes - of course I should have told you exactly where the error occurs.
I get a normal Runtime-error 70, Permission denied

No code was changed. Only data entry as they have done every day for years already. There are about 150 of these files. The data then gets imported into a main system manager and is summarized
